# How to condense many if-statements into something smaller and more readable?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, conways-game-of-life

I am working on code for game of life. And one of the functions is supposed to "evolve" the current set of cells. This means that I have to have some conditions and if the if-statement meets the condition then the cell becomes a DEAD or a ALIVE cell.

However, there are only some next cells which are being initialized, so I would have to set the rest of the next cells to DEAD who are not affected by the conditions.

Since there are four conditions I would like to condense my if-statements to the smallest possible amount.

The conditions are:

- A cell which has 0 or 1 living neighbours dies next generation.
- A cell which has 2 or 3 living neighbours lives next generation.
- A cell which has 4 or more living neighbours dies next generation.
- An empty cell which has exactly 3 living neighbours becomes a live
  cell next generation.

I've tried fitting as many of the conditions into one if-statement and an else-statement at the if, meaning if non of the cells meet the conditions it will automatically be set to DEAD. Such that all cell in `field[i][j].next` are either dead or alive.

I would like to mention that the array  `field[i][j].current` is already initialized with DEAD and ALIVE cells.

```
  void evolve(const int rows,const int cols,cell field[rows][cols], int 
    NeighbourCounter[i][j]){

       CellNeighbour(rows, cols,field,NeighbourCounter);

       for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++){
         for(int j =0;j<cols;j++){
           if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE  && NeighbourCounter[i][j] < 2){
              field[i][j].next == DEAD;
           }
           if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE && NeighbourCounter[i][j] == ||NeighbourCounter[i][j] == 2){
               field[i][j].next = ALIVE;
           } 
           if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE && NeighbourCounter[i][j] >= 4){
                field[i][j].next = DEAD;
           }
           if(field[i][j].current == DEAD && NeighbourCounter[i][j] == 3){
                field[i][j].next = ALIVE;
           }
         }
     else{
            field[i][j].next = DEAD;
     }
    }
```

`NeighbourCounter` is an array which calculates how many ALIVE neighbours each cell has.

The expected output should be that `field[rows][cols]` should be updated and the updated version is stored in ``field[rows][cols].next`.

Comment: English is not my native language so if you would need me to explain it further, ask, and I will try to explain it better.

Comment: alias the `field[i][j].current` and such with a temporary variable, you need only one if for `alive`.

Comment: If `.current` can be DEAD or ALIVE only, instead of checking it in every if, just check it once `if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE) { .... } else { .. }`.

Comment: The code shown has missing and unbalanced braces. Please fix.

Comment: @alk It should be fixed now

Comment: One way (unrelated to the `if`/`else`) it can be made more readable is to use variables instead of repeating `field[i][j]` - for example `field *cell = &field[i][j]` and then use `cell->current` and `cell->next`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. See `for(int j =0;j<cols;j++) {
... }
         else { ...`

Comment: Do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be ununderstandable. Add updates. I rolled back your last change though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest and clearest to simply `switch` on the value of the neighbour count, like this:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < rows;  ++i) {
    for (int j = 0;  j < cols;  ++j) {
        switch (NeighbourCounter[i][j]) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            /* cell dies without enough support */
            field[i][j].next = DEAD; /* I assume you meant =, not == */
            break;
        case 2:
            /* two neighbours can support a live cell */
            field[i][j].next = field[i][j].current;
            break;
        case 3:
            /* three neighbours can resurrect a dead one */
            field[i][j].next = ALIVE;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            /* more than three is a crowd */
            field[i][j].next = DEAD;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid value %d from NeighbourCounter\n",
                    NeighbourCounter[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see that `case 2` is the only one in which the `current` value is needed; all the others depend only on the number of neighbours.

Comment: Since I would need to initalize the rest of my cells with DEAD, shouldn't default then be ``field[i][j].next = DEAD``?

Comment: Oh I see. cells with 0 neighbours are assigned to be DEAD. If I understand it correctly?

Comment: The switch covers the possible cases 0..8, and `default` is just there for debugging (I perhaps should have made that an `assert()`, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 2):

> How to condense many if-statements into something smaller and more
>   readable?

You are using a bad formatting of the code. 
For example it is unclear with which if statement the following else statement is pared.

```
 else{
        field[i][j].next = DEAD;
 }
```

A bad formatting of code usually is a source of many bugs (including logical errors).:)

All these if statements

```
      if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE  && NeighbourCounter[i][j]<2){
           field[i][j].next == DEAD;
        }
         if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE && NeighbourCounter[i][j] ==3 
||NeighbourCounter[i][j] ==2 ){
          field[i][j].next = ALIVE;
        }
         if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE && NeighbourCounter[i][j] >= 4 
){
           field[i][j].next = DEAD;
         }
//...
```

can be rewritten like

```
if ( field[i][j].current == ALIVE )
{
    if ( NeighbourCounter[i][j] < 2 )
    {
        field[i][j].next == DEAD;
    }
    else if ( NeighbourCounter[i][j] < 4 )
    {
        field[i][j].next = ALIVE; 
    }
    else 
    {
        field[i][j].next = DEAD;     
    }
}
else if ( field[i][j].current == DEAD )
{
    if ( NeighbourCounter[i][j] == 3 )
    {
        field[i][j].next = ALIVE;
    }    
}
// ...
```

This makes the code more readable.

As an alternative approach you can use a switch statement like for example this

```
switch ( field[i][j].current )
{
    case ALIVE:
    {
        // ...
    }

    case DEAD:
    {
        // ...
    }

    default:
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you treat (solve?)  the "`else` without an `if` error"?

Comment: @alk As I wrote with a better formatting of the code. It will be visible what is wrong. I think there is a typo in the code snippet in the question. But it is not related to the question.

Comment: *I* know what is wrong, but I do not know how to fix it, as there seems to be something missing with the code shown. So I wondered what your crystal ball obviously seems to have told you to be able to rewrite the question's code without errors... ;)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The alternative with using switch-statments looks the "cleanest". I will try writing my code using this. So the deafult would assign DEAD for the given cell, so that it  initializes the rest of the cells? I've had problems with this since when I print out my field[i][j].next with all the new values I get a array ccontaining garbage.

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia It is another question. You can rewrite your code and then ask a new question where you'll describe what errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

One powerful technique for encoding functions is [lookup tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table). The number of neighbors is limited to the range 0...9, and the number of states is 2, so you can use a lookup table of size 20:

```
bool NewStateLUT[2][10] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // new states for dead cells
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  // new states for alive cells
};
```

The code which uses this table:

```
whatever.next = NewStateLUT[whatever.current][NeighbourCounter];
```

This code assumes that `DEAD` is 0 and `ALIVE` is equal to 1. It might be necessary to adjust the syntax if `DEAD` and `ALIVE` are enumerators.

---

Since the LUT contains only 0 and 1, it is easy to use a bitmap instead of an array:

```
uint32_t NewStateBitmap = 0b0000000100'0000001100;
whatever.next = (NewStateBitmap >> (whatever.current * 10 + NeighbourCounter)) & 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A cell is alive next generation iff either it has 3 neighbours, or if it is currently alive and has two neighbours.

This is, perhaps, a little heretical, but I wonder whether the constans ALIVE and DEAD are not getting in the way. Another way would be to rename the field current to, say, now_alive and next to next_alive, and then store 0 or 1 in them.

Then the computation of next alive could be written

```
C->next_alive = (N == 3) || (C->now_alive+N) == 3;
```

where C points to the cell and N is its number of neighbours.